# Netstat: How to know if it's Human or Bot/Spider/DDOS

Tags: linux, security, firewall, web-crawler, bots

I'm using the following command to check how many connections I have from a single ip

```
netstat -anp |grep ':80' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

If it's DDOS attack(500+ connections), it's easy to detect. But I still have at any given time 60-100 connections from single Ip. Can it be a Human or it's some sort of bots/spiders?

This is what i have at the moment(it top 6).

> ```
> 48 217.212.230.***
> 54 46.63.105.***
> 55 62.235.175.***
> 56 79.235.188.***
> 60 178.27.93.***
> 63 31.16.96.***
> ```

This server is for dynamic content. (Apache2, keepalive off)

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't see how this is programming related. Perhaps more suitable on [sf]?

Comment: If you're seeing 500+ connections from one IP-address that would surely be a "DoS" not a "DDoS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that your HTTP server is not configured to support keepalive! Configure that first of all.

If you do not configure keepalive, the browser will open one connection to your server *for each element in the page*. With keepalive, it opens only one for many elements, depending on how your keepalive is configured.

Also, consider using cache directives: static content does not need to be downloaded each time.

If you use Apache, it is done by the core (for keepalive) and mod_expires (for cache directives). Keepalive and mod_expires are the two MOST important things to configure if you want a performant website.

Comment: I'm using mod_expires. Keepalive is good for static content... i have very few images there and using keepalive degrade the performance in my case.

Comment: It degrades if you don't have images. I have another server for static content with keepalive (nginx).

Comment: Ah, OK. You didn't say that in your initial post! Care to reedit and comment your setup anymore? Also, shouldn't this really go to serverfault?

Comment: reopened http://serverfault.com/questions/343057/netstat-how-to-know-if-its-human-or-bot-spider-ddos

Answer (score 1):

you can't find out this while NAT exists in internet. If you have web server and your single page consists from ~50 elements (css files, pictures, other elements) you get ~50 sessions from single IP (if there is not NAT) that generate browser with one click.

Comment: Could be, but i showed only top 6 ips. most with 1-6 connections.